# Solving Permutation and Combinations Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

For this question:

> The word MOBILE consists of the three consonants M, B, L and the three vowels O, I, E. How many different arrangements of all the letters of the word MOBILE are possible if the vowels must be next to each other?

What do I need to use; Permutation or Combination?

Comment: Maybe you can review a bunch of related questions, else you'll be lost forever: http://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/permutations_combinations.php

Comment: You can use either, depending on exactly how you do the problem.  Please post your working and explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: "*What do I need to use*" - Don't bother limiting yourself to considering questions as *just* permutation questions or combination questions... go more basic and general than that and refer to it as a **multiplication principle** question.  Any permutation or combination question can be rephrased more generally as a multiplication principle question.  **Hint:** Arrange the letters `MBLV` and then afterwards, replace `V` by an arrangement of `OIE`.

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, "MOBILE" is not a viable arrangement of letters... Is that correct? Otherwise, that's more than a little bit misleading.

Comment: @AlexLi it is indeed not., `MOBILE` does not pass the requirement that all vowels be adjacent, however arrangements such as `MBLOIE` and `MLIEOB` would count.

Comment: If order matters - you're looking for a **permutation**.  If order does not matter, you're looking for a **combination.**  In this case, the vowels must be next to each other, so you're looking for a permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 positions to place the set of vowels {OIE} : OIExxx, xOIExx, xxOIEx and xxxOIE.
For each position, permutation of OIE gives 3!
Permutation of consonants gives 3!
Thus, $4 \times 3! \times 3! = 144$